# Make all Controls on a Form read-only at once

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Does anyone have a piece of code to make all Controls (or even all TextBoxes) in a Form which is read-only at once without having to set every Control to read-only individually?

Comment: @Raulp I don't think "which is" is correct here. The Form is not read-only, but the controls should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Form:

```
if (_cached == null)
{
    _cached = new List<TextBox>();

    foreach(var control in Controls)
    {
        TextBox textEdit = control as TextBox;
        if (textEdit != null)
        {
            textEdit.ReadOnly = false;
            _cached.Add(textEdit);
        }
    }
} 
else
{
    foreach(var control in _cached)
    {            
        control .ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

Add recursion also (Controls can be placed into other controls (panels)).

Comment: I think storing in a cache increases the performance. You'll however have to consider the allowing the user to refresh the cache. Your code also does not iterate through nested controls (like Textboxes placed inside Panels). Overall, it's a good solution.

Comment: @Alex Essilfie I wrote: "Add recursion also" :), there is no any mentions about dynamic code creation to reset _cache (see "in Form" no out of Form). Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Write an extension method which gathers controls and child controls of specified type:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildControls<T>(this Control control) where T : Control
{
    var children = control.Controls.OfType<T>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls<T>(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

Gather TextBoxes on the form (use `TextBoxBase` to affect `RichTextBox`, etc - @Timwi's solution):

```
IEnumerable<TextBoxBase> textBoxes = this.GetChildControls<TextBoxBase>();
```

Iterate thru collection and set read-only:

```
private void AreTextBoxesReadOnly(IEnumerable<TextBoxBase> textBoxes, bool value)
{
    foreach (TextBoxBase tb in textBoxes) tb.ReadOnly = value;
}
```

If want - use caching - @igor's solution

Comment: it does not return textboxes from panels/gb.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to write yourself a utility function to do this. You can iterate over the form’s controls and then each control’s child controls recursively. For example:

```
public static void SetEnableOnAllControls(Control parentControl, bool enable)
{
    parentControl.Enabled = enable;
    foreach (Control control in parentControl.Controls)
        SetEnableOnAllControls(control, enable);
}

[...]

// inside your form:
SetEnableOnAllControls(this, false);
```

This doesn’t take care of `ToolStrip`s, which aren’t controls. You could write a separate, similar method for those.

Notice that the above disables the form itself too. If you don’t want that, try this:

```
public static void SetEnableOnAllChildControls(Control parentControl, bool enable)
{
    foreach (Control control in parentControl.Controls)
    {
        control.Enabled = enable;
        SetEnableOnAllChildControls(control, enable);
    }
}
```

If you really meant the **ReadOnly** property, which is only relevant for **TextBoxes**, try this:

```
public static void SetReadOnlyOnAllControls(Control parentControl, bool readOnly)
{
    if (parentControl is TextBoxBase)
        ((TextBoxBase) parentControl).ReadOnly = readOnly;
    foreach (Control control in parentControl.Controls)
        SetReadOnlyOnAllControls(control, readOnly);
}
```

Comment: Could put an `else` into that last snippet: `TextBox` controls aren't containers.

Answer (score 3):

I would use reflection to check to see if the generic Control object has an Enabled property.

```
private static void DisableControl(Control control)
{
    PropertyInfo enProp = control.GetType().GetProperty("Enabled");
    if (enProp != null)
    {
        enProp.SetValue(control, false, null);
    }

    foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
    {
        DisableControl(ctrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.Enabled = false;
```

Depends on what you doing really, you might want to consider putting the control within a panel and disabling that.

Comment: Cool solution. If you combine it with <style> :disabled { background: white;  color: black; }</style> it becomes quite good. The remaining disadvantage is that users cannot select text and copy.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
foreach (var textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    textBox.ReadOnly = true;
```

Edit: This is not such a good solution it seems: see Timwi's comment.

Comment: ① Doesn’t take nested controls into account, i.e. works only on the top-level controls; ② Should use `TextBoxBase` so that it affects other text-box-like controls too (e.g. `RichTextBox`).

Answer (score 0):

I just developed a recursive solution that handles any kind of Web Control, using a simple static method and ASP.NET polymorphysm.

```
/// <summary>
/// Handle "Enabled" property of a set of Controls (and all of the included child controls through recursivity)
/// By default it disable all, making all read-only, but it can also be uset to re-enable everything, using the "enable" parameter 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="controls">Set of controls to be handled. It could be the entire Page.Controls set or all of the childs of a given control (property "Controls" of any Control-derived class)</param>
/// <param name="enable">Desired value of the property "enable" of each control. </param>
public static void DisableControls(ControlCollection controls, bool enable = false)
{
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        var wCtrl = control as WebControl;
        if (wCtrl != null)
        {
            wCtrl.Enabled = enable;
        }

        if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
            DisableControls(control.Controls, enable);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Enable a set of Controls (and all of the included child controls through recursivity).
/// Friendly name for DisableControls(controls, true), that achieve the same result.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Controls">Set of controls to be handled. It could be the entire Page.Controls set or all of the childs of a given control (property "Controls" of any Control-derived class)</param>
public static void EnableControls(ControlCollection controls)
{
    DisableControls(controls, true);
}
```

This is tested and looks fairly fast (less than a millisecond in a web form with 25+ controls to be disabled).

If you prefer an extension method, i think it should be enough to change the solution as follows:

```
public static void DisableControls(this Control control, bool enable = false)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
    {
        var wCtrl = ctrl as WebControl;
        if (wCtrl != null)
        {
            wCtrl.Enabled = enable;
        }

        if (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
            ctrl.DisableControls(enable);
    }
}

public static void EnableControls(this Control control)
{
    control.DisableControls(true);
}
```